# Mariabackup ignoring --target-dir

Tags: python, mariadb, mysql-python

I'm in the process of automating our mariadb backup jobs into a python program. However for some reason it appears that the --target-directory parameter, although being passed correctly and validated by printing, is ignored when running the actual command from os.system. code below:

```
import os
import datetime, time
import mysql.connector as mariadb


unix_socket = "/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"
currentdate = datetime.datetime.now()
bkp_path = time.strftime("/%Y/%m-%d/%H%M")
ro_status = ("show global variables like 'read_only%'")
dblist = ("show databases")
db = mariadb.connect(user='pytest', password='pytest', unix_socket=unix_socket)
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute(ro_status)
result = cur.fetchall()
for r in result:
        if "OFF" in r:
            cur.execute(dblist)
            dbs = cur.fetchall()
            for d in dbs:
                dbstr = ''.join(d)
                bkp_path = "/backups/" + dbstr + time.strftime("/%Y/%m-%d/%H%M/")
                bkp_cmd = "sudo mariabackup --backup --databases='" + dbstr + "' --target-directory=" + bkp_path +"  --user pytest --password=pytest --no-lock"
                try:
                    os.stat(bkp_path)
                except:
                    os.makedirs(bkp_path)
                try:
                   # print(bkp_cmd)
                    os.system(bkp_cmd)
                except:
                        print("Problem running backup on this host")
        else:
            print(h + " is read only and will not be backed up")
```

Example of the printed command:
sudo mariabackup --backup --databases="testdbBA" --target-directory=/backups/testdbBA/2019/03-06/1659/ --user pytest --password=pytest --no-lock

even when run seperatly via the printed block - it attempts to write to my local home directory and not to the specified target dir.

Comment: looks like it's --target-dir and not --target-directory https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariabackup-options/#-target-dir

Comment: Sometimes its the simple things that you miss while debugging your own code!. This was the problem - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its --target-dir not --target-directory

thanks to MFisherKDX